# Get complete Datetime but group by Date only. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have data like this:

```
Value|Date
0,055|2015-01-01 12:30:00.000
0,024|2015-01-01 15:30:00.000
0,023|2015-01-02 13:30.00.000
```

I need to get the max value per day and the time when it happens. So far I can get the max value without problems but because of the group by I only get the day without time. How can I get the complete datetime grouping by day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Value,
            [Date],
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) ORDER BY Value DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  Value,
        [Date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you very much for the quick answer. So MAX was not the way then.

Comment: @Mbastias not directly at least. With `MAX` you could've joined that result with the original table to get what you wanted (assuming no duplicates for the max value on a day)

Comment: If you do want to consider the case where the maximal value is obtained at more than one time, just change `row_number()` to `rank()`